# How to see that the cyclotomic extension is a separable extension?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, galois-extensions, cyclotomic-fields

> $\mathbb{F} \subset \mathbb{E}$ is a cyclotomic extension, if
> $\mathbb{E}$ is the splitting field of $x^n-1$ over $\mathbb{F}$.

We were directly told that $\mathbb{E} \mid \mathbb{F}$ is a Galois extension. $\mathbb{E}$ being normal is given, it is a splitting field of $x^n-1$. But what about separability? I do not remember being given a criteria to see separability of an extension, so **how can I see that this is a separable extension?**. I vaguely remembered looking for possible criterions for a separable extension but it wasn't exactly helpful (for my level).

**Edit:** as Ravi Fernando suggested, we are under the assumption that $\text{char}(\mathbb{F})=p$ prime, and $p \nmid n$.

Comment: $x^n-1$ has no repeated roots, no roots in common with its (formal) derivative, so we're in the separable case.

Comment: Are we working in characteristic 0?  If we're in characteristic $p$, then you may want to reduce to the case $p \nmid n$:  say $n = p^k m$ with $p \nmid m$; then $(x^n - 1) = (x^m - 1)^{p^k}$.

Comment: In general the splitting field of $f\in K[x]$ is separable iff $f = \prod_j f_j^{e_j}$ with each $f_j\in K[x]$ separable. The standard non-example is $x^p-y^p=(x-y)^p$ which is irreducible and non-separable in $\Bbb{F}_p(y^p)[x]$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson But isn't that only clarifying that $x^n -1$ is separable? Not the extension itself. I tried checking what are the elements of this extension (which are polynomials of the form $\mathbb{F}[\varepsilon_n]_{n-1}$), but can't really get anywhere.

Comment: @reuns I see, that answers the question. Can you point me towards a lecture note to see why? And turn your comment into an answer?